# Eclipselink not compatible with spring?

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink

I'm trying to adapt eclipselink to my project in which I'm using spring. When I try to create named query using eclipselinks EntityManagerFactory

```
public class Test {

    private static final String FIND_ALL_TEST_ENTITIES = "SELECT te.id FROM TestEntity te";

        public Test(EntityManager entityManager){
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
            entityManagerFactory.addNamedQuery("FIND_ALL_TEST_ENTITIES", entityManager.createQuery(FIND_ALL_TEST_ENTITIES));
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'test' defined in class path resource [com/github/bilak/eclipselinkspringbug/config/Config.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.bilak.eclipselinkspringbug.test.Test]: Factory method 'test' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61 cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at com.github.bilak.eclipselinkspringbug.Application.main(Application.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.github.bilak.eclipselinkspringbug.test.Test]: Factory method 'test' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61 cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61 cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.addNamedQuery(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:625) ~[eclipselink-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2.v20151217-774c696]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:541) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.addNamedQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.github.bilak.eclipselinkspringbug.test.Test.<init>(Test.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.github.bilak.eclipselinkspringbug.config.Config.test(Config.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.github.bilak.eclipselinkspringbug.config.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e1c89b1.CGLIB$test$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.github.bilak.eclipselinkspringbug.config.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e1c89b1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$38d568ea.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.github.bilak.eclipselinkspringbug.config.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e1c89b1.test(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I've created [sample project](https://github.com/bilak/eclipselinkspringbug) on github. Invoke `mvn clean spring-boot:run` to see the issue. Is this error related to eclipselink or to spring more?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you even registering named queries like that in stead of using the default `orm.xml`. If you already wanted this yu would need to do it in an `ApplicationListener` which has a `@PersistenceContext` on an `EntityManager` field to retrieve a transactional instance. There is here no guarantee that the EntityManger is fully ready.

Comment: I'm using another framework which is working this way [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/df54dcf98807751a0368ee2e9906879b7f495330/core/src/main/java/org/axonframework/saga/repository/jpa/JpaSagaRepository.java) so I'm just finding the way how to add all together.

Comment: Which also uses a managed entity manager and you are just injecting it. If you are using Axon then inject the provider just like they do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I also tried to do something like @Bean
    EntityManagerProvider entityManagerProvider() {
        return new ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider();
    } in my project, but that doesn't helped me. [here](https://github.com/bilak/axonframework-poc/blob/master/infrastructure/src/main/java/com/github/bilak/axonframework/poc/infrastructure/configuration/AxonConfiguration.java) is my axon poc where it's configured.

Comment: "Why are you even registering named queries like that" ? You mean why is he using __JPA standard__ methods ? That method is there for the case where someone wants to dynamically register a named query, and is a valid use case. Maybe Spring doesn't support it(?), but that is no reason not to do it.

Comment: It's working with hibernate, but not with eclipselink. So I'm just wondering if this is spring or eclipselink issue (I bet that's springs one).

Comment: Ok so for those who will find this question let's look if [this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13957) is resloved

Answer (score 0):

This is dodging the question in a way as I don't know what the cause of your issue is, but I'm using Spring Data JPA with EclipseLink with no problems.

Using Spring Data JPA you can re-write your code as follows:

```
public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, String> {
}
```

and therefore do your query like this. No named queries in sight.

```
List<TestEntity> testData = testEntityRepository.findAll();
```

See the Spring Data JPA docs for more detail.

Comment: basically functionality of EntityManagerFactory.addNamedQuery() is not working. I have many projects where I'm using spring + eclipselink.